# JSON is loaded with missing key/value pairs

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, axios

I am using Axios to load a static JSON from the React application server, and upon reading the files, there are many key/value pairs missing.

The JSON file in question is asset-manifest.json, which includes all the assets (media, css, js) files in the app, and is generated in the build process by webpack. I use this file as reference to pre-load the images for the website.

The JSON file looks like this (ellipsis added by me, ofc):

```
{
  "files": {
    "main.js": "/static/js/main.04cbf801.chunk.js",
    "main.js.map": "/static/js/main.04cbf801.chunk.js.map",
    "runtime-main.js": "/static/js/runtime-main.ed6fc4d3.js",
    "runtime-main.js.map": "/static/js/runtime-main.ed6fc4d3.js.map",
    "static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css": "/static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css",
    "static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js": "/static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js",
    "static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js.map": "/static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js.map",
    "static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css": "/static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css",
    "static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js": "/static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js",
    "static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js.map": "/static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js.map",
    "index.html": "/index.html",
    "precache-manifest.093a3239b1d438e30c3887d109b2e7b2.js": "/precache-manifest.093a3239b1d438e30c3887d109b2e7b2.js",
    "service-worker.js": "/service-worker.js",
    "static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css.map": "/static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css.map",
    "static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css.map": "/static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css.map",
    "static/media/ANKLES.6d795be0.svg": "/static/media/ANKLES.6d795be0.svg",
    "static/media/ARMS.8418bd6e.svg": "/static/media/ARMS.8418bd6e.svg",
    (...)
  },
  (...)
}
```

And there is nothing extraordinary in the key/value pairs that are missing. In total, these are about 15 missing entries, from a total of more than 400. For example, these are some of the key/value pairs missing:

```
"static/media/testa.png": "/static/media/testa.0b92a7e4.png",
"static/media/Osso01.png": "/static/media/Osso01.9949a55e.png",
"static/media/CabeloHomem01.png": "/static/media/CabeloHomem01.258b6c19.png"
```

This is the code I am using to load the JSON:

```
axios.get("asset-manifest.json")
  .then(manifest => {
    // entries in manifest are already missing at this point
    // do stuff with manifest
  })
```

I tried using fetch instead of Axios, for the same result.

BTW, if I copy the JSON code and parse it in the console/terminal, all entries are parsed as expected.

As a workaround, I can embed the related images in the code using base 64, but that's a last resort that I'd prefer to avoid.

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

is working fine with `fetch` first check your response in the postman or any other that you like

```js
let payload = {
  token: 'p1ztA-3ZEYrX2wJAa_juSg',
  data: {
    'static/media/testa.png': '/static/media/testa.0b92a7e4.png',
    'static/media/Osso01.png': '/static/media/Osso01.9949a55e.png',
    'static/media/CabeloHomem01.png':
      '/static/media/CabeloHomem01.258b6c19.png',
    'main.js': '/static/js/main.04cbf801.chunk.js',
    'main.js.map': '/static/js/main.04cbf801.chunk.js.map',
    'runtime-main.js': '/static/js/runtime-main.ed6fc4d3.js',
    'runtime-main.js.map': '/static/js/runtime-main.ed6fc4d3.js.map',
    'static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css': '/static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css',
    'static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js': '/static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js',
    'static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js.map': '/static/js/2.448c4959.chunk.js.map',
    'static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css': '/static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css',
    'static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js': '/static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js',
    'static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js.map': '/static/js/3.1605bce2.chunk.js.map',
    'index.html': '/index.html',
    'precache-manifest.093a3239b1d438e30c3887d109b2e7b2.js':
      '/precache-manifest.093a3239b1d438e30c3887d109b2e7b2.js',
    'service-worker.js': '/service-worker.js',
    'static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css.map':
      '/static/css/2.f5a05697.chunk.css.map',
    'static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css.map':
      '/static/css/3.d7d661be.chunk.css.map',
    'static/media/ANKLES.6d795be0.svg': '/static/media/ANKLES.6d795be0.svg',
    'static/media/ARMS.8418bd6e.svg': '/static/media/ARMS.8418bd6e.svg',
  },
};

fetch('https://app.fakejson.com/q', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
  },
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

Comment: Well, it does work with Insomnia/Postman, but still, no game with axios/fetch in the react app.

Comment: Ok, this probably has something to do with cache, since it now seems to be working fine. But that's just weird, since I had cleaned my cache before, more than once.